# Why does a stretch IK shrink?

Tags: rigging, transforms, inverse-kinematics

I have two IK chains for my leg.
One has stretch enabled, the other one doesn't so I can blend smoothly between them.

In the default position the two chains align perfectly.

[image]

Something I've noticed though: When I move the IK target so the chain folds, the chain with IK stretch enabled becomes a little smaller.

[image]

Here as a gif in case it helps to convey my problem:

[image]

I just want it to extend when the IK target goes too far but not get smaller when the IK chain folds. Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we enable stretch on IK bones, with 1.0 stretch, we can see that Blender fully prefers scaling the bones over rotating the bones:

[image]

With IK stretch set to 1.0 on both bones in the IK chain, no rotation occurs whatsoever.

But if we change the stretch value on both bones to some very low value, like 0.001, Blender will prefer rotation:

[image]

Now, the bones will still stretch to meet the distant IK target, since no amount of rotation will allow them to reach it, but they will prefer rotation when it is possible, so they will stretch very, very little when the IK target is near.

We will notice that despite this very low value, there is still a slight difference between stretch and no stretch:

[image]

If this slight difference is important, it's possible to get rid of it with a bit of complexity.  We'll sandwich in a new parent to our IK chain which first copies then limits the scale of another bone that stretches to the target:

[image]

Now, when the target is near, our IK chain inherits a scale of 1: first copied from a low scale, then limited to a minimum of 1 in all axes.  So the IK chain inherits its regular old scale of 1.0, and rotates only.  But when the IK target is distant, the IK bones inherit a large scale unaffected by any limits, and the deforming bones stretch.

Comment: Smart! I'll give it a shot, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The stretch constraint doesn't really have a way to be told to

On your stretch bone, you can add a Limit Scale constraint.

Enable the minimum Y to 1, and the maximum X/Z to 1. This way, the stretch bone can only stretch but not squash:

[image]

In addition, I highly recommend you to look this tutorial to explore different IK setups:

[Pierrick Picaut: The perfect IK rig in Blender ? - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBIdruWylDQ)

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I knew about the Limit Scale constraint but it doesn't seem to work with my setup so thanks for sharing that tutorial, I'll check it out right away!

Comment: It would help if you could upload your file one [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your question to embed the download link, that way we can see your specific ik setup and adapt our answers to it.